# how to get value of each table row using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Hello i have these code.

```
<div class="col-md-6"> <br><br>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th> Subject </th>
                <th> Schedule </th>
                <th> Day </th>
                <th> Slots </th>
                <th> Sections </th>
                <th> Action </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                foreach($Subjects as $row) 
                {
                    $course = $this->session->userdata('course');
                    if($course == 'BSITWMA' || $course == 'BSCSSE' || $course == 'BSITDA' || $course == 'BSITGDD')
                    {

                        if($row->ite == '1' ) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td id="subj_code" name="subj_code">' .$row->subject_code. '</td>';
                            echo '<td id="sched_time" name="sched_time">' .$row->schedule_timestart. ' - ' .$row->schedule_timeend.' </td>';
                            echo '<td id="day" name="day">' .$row->schedule_day. '</td>';
                            echo '<td id="slot" name="slot">' .$row->slots. '</td>';
                            echo '<td id="sect_code" name="sect_code">' .$row->section_code. '</td>';
                            echo '<td > <button id = "btn-add" class="btn" > Reserve </button > </td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        if($row->coe == '1' ) {
                           echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td id="subj_code" name="subj_code">' .$row->subject_code. '</td>';
                            echo '<td id="sched_time" name="sched_time">' .$row->schedule_timestart. ' - ' .$row->schedule_timeend.' </td>';
                            echo '<td id="day" name="day">' .$row->schedule_day. '</td>';
                            echo '<td id="slot" name="slot">' .$row->slots. '</td>';
                            echo '<td id="sect_code" name="sect_code">' .$row->section_code. '</td>';
                            echo '<td > <button id = "btn-add" class="btn" > Reserve </button > </td>';
                            echo '</tr>'; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I have updated my code and this is what it looks like now.

what i want is to when i press the button. i will retrieve all the values and use it to insert into the database.

i dont have any code yet for the retrieving of value part.

i have the jquery part like this, and i still dont have any idea how to get the values in each TD.

```
$('button').on('click',function() {
    var rowCount = $('#mhTable >tbody >tr').length;


});
```

Comment: Display your controller and model get function

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i dont have any yet in the controller and model part.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the ancestor <td> element of the button and get the values by accessing the text element of the sibling <td> elements using the jQuery .each() function.

The code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn-add").on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
        $(this).parent('td').siblings().each(function() {
            values.push($(this).text());
        });

        console.log(values);
    });
});
```

Here I pass the values to an array for simplicity but you can pass these values using ajax or whatever other method you use to send values to the database.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/animakuz/b6qkcgjo/) with this example in practise

Comment: uhm how will i get the values from the array one by one? and give the values to a separate variables.

Comment: You can use a for loop to go through the array. But now looking at some other comments I think there's some information missing about your situation in order to give a sufficient answer. The answer I gave is directed solely at getting the values directly from the elements.

Comment: ohh okay. i really dont know what approach will i do in order for me to get the values of each TD.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this for each of your variables within your foreach?

```
$subject_code = $row->subject_code;
```

and then you can use that variable for whatever you choose (such as your query)